# null object reference error on Synthetic Binding from within Class

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm a beginner with Android Studio and Kotlin.  I get the following error when trying to change the text of a TextView using Synthetic Binding from within my class.

```java
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oppenheimer.myapplication/com.oppenheimer.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

The code up to "Some other text" works but when I try with "Very new phrase" from within the class it crashes. It seems to be a common error but I'm not finding other posts that match my issue.

Here is my code

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MyText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.oppenheimer.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyText.text = "Some other text"
        val myClass = MyClass()
        myClass.MyFunction()

    }
}
```

MyClass.kt

```
package com.oppenheimer.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MyClass : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun MyFunction () {

       MyText.text = "Very new phrase"
    }
}
```

Full Error

```
2020-05-02 13:13:50.784 3632-3632/com.oppenheimer.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oppenheimer.myapplication, PID: 3632
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oppenheimer.myapplication/com.oppenheimer.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:163)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:738)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:692)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:479)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:214)
        at com.oppenheimer.myapplication.MyClass._$_findCachedViewById(Unknown Source:25)
        at com.oppenheimer.myapplication.MyClass.MyFunction(MyClass.kt:10)
        at com.oppenheimer.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

How do I change the layout from within a class?  What is the "right" way to do this?  Should I Pass the TextView into the class?

Thanks

Comment: i think it is happening because the class Myclass is an activity class, and you cannot use it like normal class initialization to use and call methods, try removing AppCompatActivity() from MyClass , it can work

Comment: Without AppCompatActivity() then MyText.text is not available inside the class (Unresolved Reference)

Comment: so basically you are trying to change the text inside textview by calling the function `MyFunction()` of `MyClass` right? and MyClass dosent have any view associated with it ?

Comment: You can have the `MyClass` as a Simple Java / Kotlin class with a method `MyFunction` which returns a string and set the returned text in your `MainActivity` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should not be trying to access a layout item from within another class, which is why you get an error.

Move it to the MainActivty's onCreate() function:

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyText.text = "Some other text"
        val myClass = MyClass()
        myClass.MyFunction()
        MyText.text = "Very new phrase"

    }
}
```

MyClass.kt

```
class MyClass : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun MyFunction () {
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to, you could access MyText and alter its value by passing a reference of it to MyClass and to MyFunction() as a parameter.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.oppenheimer.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MyText.text = "Some other text"
        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.MyText)
        val myClass = MyClass(textView)
        myClass.MyFunction(textView)
    }
}
```

**MyClass.kt**

```
package com.oppenheimer.myapplication

import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MyClass(textView: TextView) : AppCompatActivity() {

    fun MyFunction (textView: TextView) {
        textView.text = "Very new phrase"
    }
}
```

Please note also that following naming conventions is good software practice and therefore all function names should start with a small letter, myFunction().